# How to click all the fetched links from a search result in selenium using python?

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, staleelementreferenceexception

In selenium, I am grabbing some search result URL by XPATH. Now I want to click then one by one which will open then in the same browser one by one where the base URL is opened so that I can switch between then. How can I do that? I am giving my code below.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

serv_obj = Service("F:\Softwares\Selenium WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=serv_obj)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

url = "https://testautomationpractice.blogspot.com/"
driver.get(url)


driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='Wikipedia1_wikipedia-search-input']").send_keys("selenium")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='submit']").click()

search_result = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='wikipedia-search-result-link']/a")
links = []
for item in search_result:
    url_data = item.get_attribute("href")
    links.append(url_data)
    print(url_data)
print(len(links))
print(links)
```

I have grabbed all the links from the search result by using customized XPATH. I am being able yo print them also. But I want to open/click on the every resulted link one by one in the same browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that as following:
Get the list of the links.
In a loop click on grabbed links.
When link is opened in a new tab switch the driver to the new opened tab.
Do there what you want to do (I simulated this by a simple delay of 1 second).
Close the new tab.
Switch back to the first tab.
Collect the list of links again since the previously collected links become [Stale reference](https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/stale-element-reference-exception-selenium-webdriver/#:%7E:text=Stale%20Element%20means%20an%20old,then%20the%20StaleElementReferenceException%20is%20thrown.).
The following code works:

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)


url = "https://testautomationpractice.blogspot.com/"
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='Wikipedia1_wikipedia-search-input']"))).send_keys("selenium")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='submit']"))).click()
links = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='wikipedia-search-result-link']/a")))
for index, link in enumerate(links):
    links[index].click()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
    links = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='wikipedia-search-result-link']/a")))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response but is there any other alternate way to click on the links which I am getting inside my lists using for loop. As in my code as you can see I am getting links. search_result = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='wikipedia-search-result-link']/a")

for item in search_result:
    url_data = item.get_attribute("href")
    ----- Here inside this for loop is it possible to click on the links which I am getting in url_data.

Comment: Looks like yes. I think my code is similar to your, just working :) What prevents you to use the approach I show in my answer with your loop? What do not work?

Comment: It works perfectly. I had made a mistake before. Sorry and thanks a lot for the solution.